# Having 6 critical vulnerabilities while installing npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, dependencies, audit

I am building a react-project for one of my client. But, when I installed react into my system, using
`npx create-react-app client --use-npm`, then it is successfully installed reactJs into my system, but later on, when looking at the results, it is throwing 6 severe vulnerabilities.

I am afraid that these could be a problem later on during development. I am building this project for some important organisation, and I don't want to be in trouble in near future.

How can I avoid these vulnerabilities (the severe ones).

Here's are my versions:

**npm** - v8.15.0
**nodeJs** - 16.17.1
**react** - 18.2.0.

How can I avoid these vulnerabilities, in many of the answers so far , I have also seen that (these vulnerabilities) could be the false alarm, and it should not affect the development later on as well.

```
# npm audit report

nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
Himanshus-MacBook-Air:connect himanshu$ npm audit
# npm audit report

nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          node_modules/react-scripts

Above is what i have got after running **'npm audit'**
```

Below is the number of vulnerabilities I am facing

```
    up to date, audited 1430 packages in 4s
    
    210 packages are looking for funding
      run `npm fund` for details
    
    6 high severity vulnerabilities
    
    To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
      npm audit fix --force
    
    Run `npm audit` for details.
    Himanshus-MacBook-Air:connect himanshu$ npm audit
    # npm audit report
    
    nth-check  <2.0.1
    Severity: high
    Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
    fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
    Will install react-scripts@2.1.3, which is a breaking change
    node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
      css-select  <=3.1.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
      node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
        svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
        Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
        node_modules/svgo
          @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
          Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
          node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
            @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
            Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
            node_modules/@svgr/webpack
              react-scripts  >=2.1.4
              Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
              node_modules/react-scripts
    
    6 high severity vulnerabilities
    
    To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
      npm audit fix --force
```

Comment: Basically, when a package manager reports that one of your dependencies has a security vulnerability, it is your job to decide if the vulnerability will affect you. Read the link for each vulnerability and make a decision. You can make several decisions per vulnerability: (1) you're not vulnerable, don't upgrade; (2) you are vulnerable and must upgrade; (3) you can't tell whether you are vulnerable and would like to upgrade anyway.

Comment: OK, so let's say you want to upgrade a dependency. If the vulnerability is in an immediate dependency, then find out if there is a more recent version. If there is, see if you can upgrade with only a minor version bump - a major version bump might not be backwards-compatible. If the vulnerability is in a dependency of a dependency, then see if you can upgrade the dependency that specifies it, again with only a minor version upgrade if you can. One the new library/libraries are in place, run your test suites to ensure everything still operates as you expect.

Comment: If you are working for an important organisation then it is up to them to verify that you have the security skills to make these decisions and to rectify them. It's certainly fine that you asked this question, but you can't farm out your infosec policy to Stack Overflow - that is just not safe. By all means do try my suggestions above, but do you have senior colleagues who can help you make the right security judgements?

Comment: HI @helfer , I really appreciate the fact that you took time in answering my question. I was having vulnerabilities by the time I posted this question over here. But, after scratching and digging  a number of possible solutions for this on stack overflow, reddit and from other sources, I came to know that, It is fine if you are having some vulnerabilities, as long as it does not hamper your application performance. So, till now , I didn't face any performance issue. I am working as an independent developer into one organization, so I had to resolve the errors by my own, if I face any!

Comment: Vulnerabilities can be about performance, but in general they are not. Think about it this way - if your security is protecting customer data or customer assets, will one of those vulnerabilities let someone steal something that does not belong to them?

Comment: You should include your `package.json` in the question to increase the chance of getting a good answer.